# how to set pie chart colors in wijmo pie chart using javascript and webservice

Tags: javascript, pie-chart, wijmo

I need to set the pie chart slices in my wijpiechart to the color retrieved from the database for that row. Using webservice to retrieve this info and javascript to render the wijpiechart. Any help would be very much appreciated.
Thanks,
Hindy

Comment: What you have started with (any code)?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the colors coming from the database in the series of the pie chart by setting 'seriesStyles' option. You may refer to the following demo sample that uses this option:
http://wijmo.com/demo/explore/?widget=PieChart&sample=Colors%20Formatting